# Can I create a global todo list in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I am new to Doxygen and have been able to create todo items in a module. Can I create a global todo list or is there a better way to get all the todo items in one place?

Answer (score 14):

All the to do items (created using the doxygen command [`\todo`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtodo)) appear together on a page called "Todo list", which is located under the "Related Pages" tab (see the image below). This page is a "global" to do list for the whole project. Notice that a page is also created for lists of bugs (cf [`\bug`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdbug)).

[image: "Related Pages" generated by doxygen, which links to the global todo list.]

You can also make your own custom pages appear under the "Related Pages" tab using the generalization of the `\todo` and `\bug` commands, 
`\xrefitem`. See the [`\xrefitem` documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem) for an example which adds a "Reminders" page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tagfile output and use it as input to another Doxygen configuration, but I've not yet successfully gotten xrefitem pages to import that way.

You can export to xml and have a parser read all your todo.xml files and combine them.